# How to draw a circle which wraps one of the poles on mercator (EPSG:4326) with Openlayers 7?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, mercator

I'd like to draw visiblity circles (i.e. solid angle of visibility around a given lat/lon point on a point at a given altitude, projected on the earth surface) and have no problem except when one of the poles is wrapped by the "circle"/projected polygon (in reality, as I use the EPSG:4326 projection, the "circle" is an ellipse with two focal points on the North-South axis, see [Tissot's Indicatrix on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tissot%27s_indicatrix)). In this case (North or south pole is wrapped), the resulting polygon misses a latitude band portion starting from the highest polygon latitude to the 90° latitude (if north pole) or lowest polygon latitude to the -90° latitude (if south pole).

See screenshots below:
**- first one: **
what I obtain using Openlayers' ol.geom.Polygon.circular(...) method in the code below:

```
 const vectorLayer4326 = new ol.layer.Vector({
     source: new ol.source.Vector(),
     style: polygon_style,
 });

 const radius = 7708025;
 let x, y;
 x = 0;
 for (y = 9; y <= 50; y += 10) {
     const circle4326 = ol.geom.Polygon.circular([x, y], radius, 128);
     vectorLayer4326.getSource().addFeature(new ol.Feature(circle4326));
 }
```

[Incorrect visibility circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Edam.jpg)

**- second one: **
what I expect to get (I obtained it using the almost same code as above, but I added a fixing method. What it does is explained below the code snippet):

```
 const vectorLayer4326 = new ol.layer.Vector({
     source: new ol.source.Vector(),
     style: polygon_style,
 });

 const radius = 7708025;
 let x, y;
 x = 0;
 for (y = 9; y <= 50; y += 10) {
     const circle4326 = **fix_OL_visi_circle_pole_vertices**(ol.geom.Polygon.circular([x, y], radius, 128));
     vectorLayer4326.getSource().addFeature(new ol.Feature(circle4326));
```

The **fix_OL_visi_circle_pole_vertices(Polygon)** method is a fix I did to correct the Polygon geometry by forcibly adding the "corners" ([-180,90], [180, 90] points for North pole and [-180,-90], [180,-90] points for South pole) when detecting a longitude leap.
But obviously, I'd rather have a clean solution

[Correct visibility circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8UcB.jpg)

And the Openlayers' map initialization:
`

```
const map4326 = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        tiles_layer,
        vectorLayer4326
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        center: [0, 0],
        zoom: 2,
    }),
});
```

`

I had the same issue with Leaflet, changed tthe projection to EPSG:3395, which solved the geometric problem, but then I couldn't fix the tiles to match the correct latitudes.
Looking in every direction, I tried to change the map display technology for OpenLayers when I saw their Tissot indicatrix example, hoping it would support the pole wrapping case.
Unfortunately, it had the same issue than Leaflet. So I analyzed the generated geometry and produced the fix described previously.

But as I am not a geographer, I hope there is a solution based on changing projections/transformations from a different projection than Mercator to the EPSG:4326 I use.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `ol.geom.Polygon.circular` does not give good results exactly at the poles because all directions are north or south.  Try limiting the latitudes to a close approximation, e.g. 89.9999999

Comment: @mike: Problem is that I give latitudes <= 50° in the example above, but as the radius is approx 7800 km, the resulting circle wraps the pole. And in the geometry generated by the `ol.geom.Polygon.circular(...)` method, the greatest latitude value doesn't exceed 86°.

Comment: It is normal to split polygons which cross the antimeridian into multipolygons, e.g. Russia and Fiji in https://openlayers.org/en/v6.10.0/examples/vector-layer.html and for polygons enclosing a pole such as Antarctica to be delimited by a split at the antimeridian.  OpenLayers can handle longitudes beyond plus/minus 180 but cannot automatically split where a pole is enclosed.

Comment: @mike: I understand that it's not easy, but I should maybe ask the Openlayers team to handle it as I did with my "fix" (but cleaner). I'm considering a pull request here. A cleaner solution than mine would be to check if a circle encloses one of the poles (distance between circle center and pole < circle radius) and in this case, when crossing the antimeridian, to insert the "mercator corners" of the map to the Polygon points (same as I did, but it would be more efficient to add those points directly in the Polygon coordinates calculus process, instead of an afterward fix). I'll try